# Convert basic SWF Shapes to SVG

Tags: php, flash, svg, shapes

I would export programmatically (in PHP) the content of a SWF file to a SVG format.  So, I tried first to export each shapes composing my file to be abble to create the static sprites later.
For that, I use the [IO_SWF](https://github.com/openpear/IO_SWF) library to read the content of the swf file.

```
FillStyles:
    [1] solid fill: #d9d2c5(ff)
    [2] solid fill: #8e7e66(ff)
    [3] solid fill: #b9ae9a(ff)
    [4] solid fill: #716044(ff)
LineStyles:
    (none)
ShapeRecords:
    ChangeStyle: MoveTo: (6.95, -10)  FillStyle: 0|2  LineStyle: 0
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (7, -9.95)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (7.2, -9.65)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (7.1, -9.45)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.85, -9)
    ChangeStyle: MoveTo: (6.85, -9)  FillStyle: 0|3  LineStyle: 0
    CurvedEdge: MoveTo: Control(6.8, -7.95) Anchor(6.9, -7.15)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.95, -6.25)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.95, -6.15)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (7, -6.15)
    ChangeStyle: MoveTo: (7, -6.15)  FillStyle: 0|1  LineStyle: 0
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.95, -5.85)
    ChangeStyle: MoveTo: (6.95, -5.85)  FillStyle: 0|2  LineStyle: 0
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.5, -5.2)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (4.15, -2.3)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (3.55, -2.15)
    ChangeStyle: MoveTo: (3.55, -2.15)  FillStyle: 0|4  LineStyle: 0
    CurvedEdge: MoveTo: Control(3.7, -3.9) Anchor(5.35, -8.85)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.45, -10.85)
    CurvedEdge: MoveTo: Control(6.55, -10.45) Anchor(6.95, -10)
    ChangeStyle: MoveTo: (6.95, -10)  FillStyle: 2|4  LineStyle: 0
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.2, -8.9)
    ChangeStyle: MoveTo: (6.2, -8.9)  FillStyle: 2|3  LineStyle: 0
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.85, -9)
    ChangeStyle: MoveTo: (6.2, -8.9)  FillStyle: 3|4  LineStyle: 0
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.15, -7.85)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.15, -7.7)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.2, -7.55)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.2, -6.9)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.25, -6.75)
    ChangeStyle: MoveTo: (6.25, -6.75)  FillStyle: 3|1  LineStyle: 0
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.35, -6.2)
    CurvedEdge: MoveTo: Control(6.4, -6) Anchor(6.7, -5.95)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (7, -6.15)
    ChangeStyle: MoveTo: (4.4, -3.2)  FillStyle: 2|4  LineStyle: 0
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (4.15, -2.95)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (3.55, -2.15)
    ChangeStyle: MoveTo: (6.95, -5.85)  FillStyle: 2|1  LineStyle: 0
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.95, -5.9)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.8, -5.95)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.7, -5.95)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.5, -5.9)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.3, -5.8)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (4.4, -3.2)
    ChangeStyle: MoveTo: (4.4, -3.2)  FillStyle: 4|1  LineStyle: 0
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.15, -5.85)
    StraightEdge: MoveTo: (6.25, -6.75)
    ChangeStyle: MoveTo: (0, 0)  FillStyle: 0|0  LineStyle: 0
```

After some research, I understood how to build a svg (composed by path tags) from these data.

```
ChangeStyle => start a new path => M x,y
StraightEdge => line => L x,y
CurvedEdge => curve => Q cx,cy,ax,ay
```

And for each path:

```
FillStyle: {FillStyle0} | {FillStyle1} (0 => no fill style)
The index is related to the FillStyles array

LineStyle: {LineStyle} (0 => line style)
The index is related to the LineStyles array
```

But this is not the correct way to browse the structure.
Using [JPEXS Decompiler](https://github.com/jindrapetrik/jpexs-decompiler) to manually export the previous sample shape, I get a perfect traced SVG.
Here is a comparative:

[My result vs what is expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlyVH.png)

My resulting svg:

```html
<path fill="rgba(185, 174, 154, 1)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" d="M 6.95 -10 L 7 -9.95 L 7.2 -9.65 L 7.1 -9.45 L 6.85 -9 L 6.95 -10" />
<path fill="rgba(217, 210, 197, 1)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" d="M 6.85 -9 Q 6.8 -7.95 6.9 -7.15 L 6.95 -6.25 L 6.95 -6.15 L 7 -6.15 L 6.85 -9" />
<path fill="rgba(142, 126, 102, 1)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" d="M 7 -6.15 L 6.95 -5.85 L 7 -6.15" />
<path fill="rgba(113, 96, 68, 1)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" d="M 6.95 -5.85 L 6.5 -5.2 L 4.15 -2.3 L 3.55 -2.15 L 6.95 -5.85" />
<path fill="rgba(142, 126, 102, 1)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" d="M 3.55 -2.15 Q 3.7 -3.9 5.35 -8.85 L 6.45 -10.85 Q 6.55 -10.45 6.95 -10 L 3.55 -2.15" />
<path fill="rgba(142, 126, 102, 1)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" d="M 6.95 -10 L 6.2 -8.9 L 6.95 -10" />
<path fill="rgba(185, 174, 154, 1)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" d="M 6.2 -8.9 L 6.85 -9 L 6.2 -8.9" />
<path fill="rgba(185, 174, 154, 1)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" d="M 6.2 -8.9 L 6.15 -7.85 L 6.15 -7.7 L 6.2 -7.55 L 6.2 -6.9 L 6.25 -6.75 L 6.2 -8.9" />
<path fill="rgba(142, 126, 102, 1)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" d="M 6.25 -6.75 L 6.35 -6.2 Q 6.4 -6 6.7 -5.95 L 7 -6.15 L 6.25 -6.75" />
<path fill="rgba(142, 126, 102, 1)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" d="M 4.4 -3.2 L 4.15 -2.95 L 3.55 -2.15 L 4.4 -3.2" />
<path fill="rgba(113, 96, 68, 1)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" d="M 6.95 -5.85 L 6.95 -5.9 L 6.8 -5.95 L 6.7 -5.95 L 6.5 -5.9 L 6.3 -5.8 L 4.4 -3.2 L 6.95 -5.85" />
```

And the JPEXS result:

```html
<path d="M7.0 -6.15 L6.95 -5.85 6.95 -5.9 6.8 -5.95 6.7 -5.95 6.5 -5.9 6.3 -5.8 4.4 -3.2 6.15 -5.85 6.25 -6.75 6.35 -6.2 Q6.4 -6.0 6.7 -5.95 L7.0 -6.15" fill="#d9d2c5" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" />
<path d="M6.95 -10.0 L7.0 -9.95 7.2 -9.65 7.1 -9.45 6.85 -9.0 6.2 -8.9 6.95 -10.0 M6.95 -5.85 L6.5 -5.2 4.15 -2.3 3.55 -2.15 4.15 -2.95 4.4 -3.2 6.3 -5.8 6.5 -5.9 6.7 -5.95 6.8 -5.95 6.95 -5.9 6.95 -5.85" fill="#8e7e66" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" />
<path d="M6.85 -9.0 Q6.8 -7.95 6.9 -7.15 L6.95 -6.25 6.95 -6.15 7.0 -6.15 6.7 -5.95 Q6.4 -6.0 6.35 -6.2 L6.25 -6.75 6.2 -6.9 6.2 -7.55 6.15 -7.7 6.15 -7.85 6.2 -8.9 6.85 -9.0" fill="#b9ae9a" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" />
<path d="M3.55 -2.15 Q3.7 -3.9 5.35 -8.85 L6.45 -10.85 Q6.55 -10.45 6.95 -10.0 L6.2 -8.9 6.15 -7.85 6.15 -7.7 6.2 -7.55 6.2 -6.9 6.25 -6.75 6.15 -5.85 4.4 -3.2 4.15 -2.95 3.55 -2.15" fill="#716044" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" />
```

All in all, how could I obtain the same well formed SVG from my data structure? I'm pretty sure there's a subtility with FillStyle0 and FillStyle1, but which?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have the source code to both programs.  It should be possible to work out what they are doing. And why the output of IO_SWF is in a different order to JPEXS.  It looks like you are closing off paths too early when they are instead supposed to be joined to others.

Comment: None of your path tags are closed. Please close the path tags first

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Indeed, I have the correct coordinates, the real difficulty consists to join them to get the same result. JPEXS seems to create one path by fillstyle: one path for each 0|{n} where n is the number associated with a fillstyle. I was able to properly understand how to join the first path, but not the others. I have read some source from JPEXS Github repository, but it seems to be a real Gaz factory.

Comment: @enxaneta By closing the paths, if you mean 'add Z at the end of the path', I get the same result. But I just realized that I was badly closing my paths: I changed d="M xStart yStart ... xStart yStart" to d="M xStart yStart ... L xStart yStart Z".

Comment: I mean this: `<path d="M7.0 -6.15 L6.95..." />` instead of: `<path d="M7.0 -6.15 L6.95..." >`

Comment: My mistake. I badly copied/pasted the HTML output, I fixed it in the main post.